# Bower install packages EPERM rename error

Tags: windows, node.js, bower

clean windows 7 professional installation with node and git.

simple bower.json

```
{
  "name": "name123456",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "closure-compiler": "http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.zip"
  }
}
```

run bower install and it dies with permission error.

[image: error]

any idea why this happens? thank u.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's a bug in bower 1.2.7 and up related to an upgraded zip library. A workaround is reinstall bower, as it will force an upgrade for the zip library:

```
bower cache clean
npm uninstall -g bower
npm install -g bower
```

For more information, see https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/991

Note that the above is not sufficient with an older version of Node (I tried 0.9.9). With latest version of node, it seems to be working fine again.

Answer (score 4):

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you, you can try the line below.

```
npm uninstall -g bower && npm update decompress-zip && npm install -g bower
```

[Source - Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5502)

Answer (score 0):

Clean the cache.

```
bower cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone else. I was getting this same error until I disabled my antivirus.